# Exporting and requiring an async function error

Tags: node.js, module, async-await, export, require

I export an async function in a file called resourcess.js like this:

```
//resourcess.js
module.exports = function(arg) {
    let do_stuff = async (arg) => {
    ...
}
```

Then i require that file in routes.js like this:

```
let importedFunc = require('./resourcess.js');
```

Finally i use it in routes.js like this:

```
app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
        var a2 = req.body.a1;
        importedFunc(a2).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        res.render('index.ejs');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.render('index.ejs');
        })
    });
```

This is the error message i get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I cannot understand what i am doing wrong....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not calling `do_stuff` and returning the promise, then the exported function isn't actually returning a promise:

```
//resourcess.js
module.exports = function(arg) {
    let do_stuff = async (arg) => {
      // something should be done inside this function
      let data = await somethingThatReturnsData(arg);
      return data;
    };
    return do_stuff(arg);
}
```

But from how this is being used, I think you want to do the following:

```
//resourcess.js
// see that async is on the actual exported function
module.exports = async function(arg) {
  let data = await somethingThatReturnsData(arg);
  // do stuff to data
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `resourcess.js` file is a function wrapping an async function.

```
//resourcess.js
module.exports = function(arg) {
    let do_stuff = async (arg) => {
    ...
}
```

You didn't call the imported function first, so the async function inside it does not exist yet.

```
app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
        var a2 = req.body.a1;
        importedFunc(a2).then(result => {
            console.log(result);
        res.render('index.ejs');
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.render('index.ejs');
        })
    });
```

To correct it, just rewrite it to `importedFunc()(a2).then`

If you want to use it like how you're using it right now, redo your `resourcess.js` implementation like this:

```
//resourcess.js
module.exports = async function do_stuff(arg) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
//resourcess.js
module.exports = async arg => {
    ...
}
```

Where `...` is the code inside your do_stuff function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for `async/await`, then stick with it and try not to mix it with promises.

```
app.post('/post', async function(req, res) {
    try {
        var a2 = req.body.a1;
        var result = await resimportedFunc(a2);
        console.log(result);
        res.render('index.ejs');
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.render('index.ejs');
    }
});
```